# Execute SQL Task in TSQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssis

I have multiple SQL tasks that execute stored procedures. I intend to `call` these `SQL tasks` in some other stored procedure. How do I do this ?

In these SQL tasks, all I have is `exec sp` statement.All these SQL tasks need to start in a stored procedure only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call individual SSIS tasks, but you can call an SSIS package from a stored procedure. The procedure so is not totally straight-forwards and I won't put instructions here, as there are [many sites which do so](http://www.bing.com/search?q=how%20to%20start%20ssis%20packagefrom%20stored%20procedure&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=how%20to%20start%20ssis%20packagefrom%20stored%20procedure&sc=0-44&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=19739d2698a84c5db55404fcb63b9323).

However, if all these tasks do is call an SP, why not just call the sp?

Comment: Thank you so much. I have 20-30 long running stored procedures so to execute them asynchronously I am using SQL tasks which otherwise get executed sequentially and in that case execution time increases.

Comment: Also, I created a package and saved it with couple of SQL tasks. Now, i do not see them in that file. How does it work ? What could be the reason,please? Thanks